# Window tkinter doesn't display when there is a connection with another device

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, tkinter, window

- I would like to connect 2 computers in order to make a kind of messenger, but I would like to use `tkinter`, in order to have windows, and use buttons and other widgets to create the interface.
- So I have 2 programs, one is the client, and the other is the server.

  - For the client, it works : the window displays, and I can send message.
  - For the server, the window doesn't display.

### client program:

```
import socket
from tkinter import *

def envoyer_msg():
    s.send(msg.get().encode())

fenetre=Tk()
fenetre.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(200,200,200,200))

texte=Label(fenetre,text="CLIENT",font=25)
texte.pack()

msg=StringVar()
saisie=Entry(fenetre,textvariable=msg,font=25)
saisie.pack()

bouton_envoyer=Button(fenetre,text="Envoyer",font=25,command=envoyer_msg)
bouton_envoyer.pack()

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('127.0.0.1',12345))
```

and here the server program :

```
import socket
from tkinter import *

def envoyer_msg():
    c.send(msg.encode())

fenetre=Tk()
fenetre.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(200,200,200,200))

texte=Label(fenetre,text="SERVEUR",font=25)
texte.pack()

msg=StringVar()
saisie=Entry(fenetre,textvariable=msg,font=25)
saisie.pack()

bouton_envoyer=Button(fenetre,text="Envoyer",font=25,command=envoyer_msg)
bouton_envoyer.pack()

print("1")

s = socket.socket()
port = 12345
s.bind(('', port))
s.listen(5)
c, addr = s.accept()
print ("Socket Up and running with a connection from",addr)

print("2")

while True:
    rcvdData = c.recv(1024).decode()
    print ("S:",rcvdData)

    print("3")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should call `mainloop()` explicitly even though you are using an IDE made with `tkinter` like Python IDLE.  Otherwise the GUI won't show up when the script is executed in a terminal.

---

The server GUI does not show up because the `while` loop blocks the `mainloop()`.  You need to put the client connection handling task in a thread:

```py
# server code
import socket
import threading
from tkinter import *

def envoyer_msg():
    c.send(msg.get().encode())

fenetre=Tk()
fenetre.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(200,200,200,200))

texte=Label(fenetre,text="SERVEUR",font=25)
texte.pack()

msg=StringVar()
saisie=Entry(fenetre,textvariable=msg,font=25)
saisie.pack()

bouton_envoyer=Button(fenetre,text="Envoyer",font=25,command=envoyer_msg)
bouton_envoyer.pack()

def server_task():
    global c

    s = socket.socket()
    port = 12345
    s.bind(('', port))
    s.listen(5)

    while True:
        print('waiting connection ...')
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print ("Socket Up and running with a connection from", addr)

        while True:
            try:
                rcvdData = c.recv(1024).decode()
                print ("Client:", rcvdData)
            except ConnectionResetError:
                print('Client disconnected')
                break

# start the client connection handling thread
threading.Thread(target=server_task, daemon=True).start()
fenetre.mainloop()
```

---

Same applies on the client side:

```py
# client code
import socket
import threading
from tkinter import *

def envoyer_msg():
    s.send(msg.get().encode())

fenetre=Tk()
fenetre.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(200,200,400,200))

texte=Label(fenetre,text="CLIENT",font=25)
texte.pack()

msg=StringVar()
saisie=Entry(fenetre,textvariable=msg,font=25)
saisie.pack()

bouton_envoyer=Button(fenetre,text="Envoyer",font=25,command=envoyer_msg)
bouton_envoyer.pack()

def client_task():
    global s
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1',12345))
    while True:
        try:
            rcvdData = s.recv(1024).decode()
            print('Server:', rcvdData)
        except ConnectionResetError:
            print('Server disconnected')
            fenetre.destroy()

# start the server connection thread
threading.Thread(target=client_task, daemon=True).start()
fenetre.mainloop()
```

---

Since you want to use GUI, better use a `Text` widget to hold the peer messages instead of using `print()`.